# Metrics for HTTP response status code for Grafana dashboard

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator

A question regarding Spring Boot, and how to get the HTTP response status code and display them into Grafana.

Setup: a Java Spring Boot application at 2.5.1 (relevant to any Spring Boot 2.x.x). The app has actuator and micrometer dependencies. App generates Prometheus metrics fine.

I am very interested in this one dashboard: The HTTP response status code. Not the time elapsed, not the count, just the HTTP status code response (responded with 200, 401, 503, etc). Because of the dependencies, I see those metrics!

`http_server_requests_seconds`

Hence, I first tried this:

`increase(http_server_requests_seconds{_ws_="my_workspace",_ns_="my_namespace",_source_="my_source", _bucket_="+Inf"}[15m])`

This seems to yield something:

[image]

I am able to see some HTTP 200, some HTTP 503, but for some reason, I am also seeing not only one 200, but bunch of them with what seems to be a time elapsed.

Is this query correct? What would be the most appropriate query in order to get the different HTTP status code response over time?

Most of all, what would be the best visualization dashboard to represents the difference HTTP status code response?

Comment: Are you using spring-webflux? Maybe this is because the app return multiple responses before a complete request of a Flux. I would make a simple test with a request to a single Mono to check.

Comment: Thanks Felipe for the comment, you are correct, indeed using Webflux. I changed to returning simple Mono, still observing the same

Comment: If you print the result of the query as a table, then you look for values that are equal for the same response 200-OK and diffefernt values for different responses 200-OK. Then you uses some prometheus operator to distinguish them...

Comment: The query returns multiple values with different labels. Remove `200` and `500` from query legend and you'll see the diffference.

Comment: Thanks @anemyte for the comment. My legends contains only this ```{{status}}``` You mean I should remove this? Change it to something else?

Comment: Just remove it for now. It'll show you all labels instead and you'll see why there's multiple 200's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grafana will add one line per distinct labels found in your Prometheus query. When you define a legend that does not contain all distinct labels, you will see multiple lines with the same legend.

*`increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[1m])` with legend `{{status}}`:*

[image: example-same-legends]

If you remove your definition of the legend, you should be able to see all labels to determine which ones create duplicate values.

*`increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[1m])` with no legend definition:*

[image: example-1]

If you restrict the query more, for example by adding the condition `{method="POST"}`, there will be less lines as well:

[image: example-2]

Another option is to **aggregate your result** to eliminate labels. Based on the question, you want to see total increase per HTTP status code. Here is an example of what I find a good way to visualise this:

*`sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[1m])) by (status)` with legend `{{status}}`:*

[image: example-aggregation]